# Why 'equality almost everywhere' is transitive?

Tags: measure-theory

Rudin RCA p.27

Let $\mu$ be a measure.

Define $f\sim g$ iff $\mu(\{x|f(x)≠g(x)\})=0$ ($f,g$ are measurable functions from $X$ to a topological space $Y$.

How come this relation $\sim$ is transitive?

Let'a assume $f\sim g$ and $g\sim h$.

By assumtion, $\{x|f(x)≠g(x)\}$ and $\{x|g(x)≠h(x)\}$ are measurable sets.

However, why this gurantees that $\{x|f(x)≠h(x)\}$ is measurable? If this is not measurable, then $\mu(\{x|f(x)≠h(x)\})$ is not defined, hence $f$ is not equivalent with $h$.

Comment: Are $f,g,h$ $\mathbb{R}$ valued, with $\mathbb{R}$ given Lebesgue measure?

Comment: @uncookedfalcon No. $f,g,h$ be any maps to a topological space $Y$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you assume $f, h$ are measurable functions (which is an acceptable assumption) then $\{x;f(x)\neq h(x)\}$ is a measurable set and we have $\{x;f(x)\neq h(x)\}\subseteq \{x;f(x)\neq g(x)\}\cup \{x;g(x)\neq h(x)\}$.

Comment: Besides if the measure is complete then such sets are always measurable.

Comment: do you mean "$\mu$ is complete" is essential?

Comment: Yes because every subset of a set with measure zero is a measurable set in a complete measure by definition.

Comment: So the relation in my post fails to be an equivalence relation for an arbitrary measure.. Thank you

Comment: In measure theory we usually consider measurable functions. In that case, as I said in the above the relation is an equivalence relation again, because $\{x; f(x)\neq h(x)\}=(f-h)^{-1} (\mathbb{R}-0)$.

Comment: @Katlus: It _is_ an equivalence relation, even if $\mu$ is not complete, because it is only _defined_ for measurable functions. And uncookedfalcon's answer shows that $\{x:f(x)\ne h(x)\}$ is measurable if $f$ and $h$ are.

Comment: @TonyK How do we have $\{x:f(x)\neq h(x)\}\subseteq \{x:f(x)\neq g(x)\}\cup \{x:g(x)\neq h(x)\}$? Was this by observation? (Other than that I follow the rest of this answer.)

Comment: @Cookie (for future readers:) suppose $x\in\{x:f(x)\ne h(x)\}$. Assuming $f(x)=g(x)$ _and_ $g(x)=h(x)$ were true, we get $f(x)=g(x)=h(x)$, which contradicts $f(x)\ne h(x)$. Thus one of $f(x)=g(x)$ or $g(x)=h(x)$ must be false.

Answer (score 2):

Since you're saying $f\sim g$ and $g\sim h$ it is implicitly given that $f,g,h$ are measurable. To show that $\mu(\{x\mid f(x)\neq h(x)\})=0$ show and use that
$$
\{x\mid f(x)=g(x)\}\cap\{x\mid g(x)=h(x)\}\subseteq\{x\mid f(x)=h(x)\}.
$$

Comment: I showed that equality, but still don't understand why $\{x|f(x)=h(x)\}$ is measurable. Let $y\in Y$ (See my edited post). If it could be shown that $\{y\}$ is a borel set, then the proof is done. If $Y$ is any topological space how come $\{y\}$ is a borel set ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming all our functions are $\mathbb{R}^n$ valued, with $\mathbb{R}^n$ given Lesbesgue measure. In general, for any two such $f,g$, $f-g$ is measurable, and so the set of points where $f \neq g$ is simply the preimage of $\mathbb{R}^n - 0$ under $f-g$, hence measurable.

*Edit*: As pointed out in other comments, for $Y$ arbitrary if the measure on $X$ is complete it follows this is an equivalence relation. I just wanted to add that if $Y$ is Hausdorff you don't need this: for any $f,g$, the set of points where $f = g$ is exactly the pullback of the diagonal of $Y \times Y$, which is closed.

Answer (score 1):

Note that:
$$\forall x\in X[f(x)\not=h(x)\implies f(x)\not=g(x) \,or\ g(x)\not=h(x)] $$

Thus:

$$\{x|f(x)\not= h(x)\}\subseteq \{x|f(x)\not=g(x)\}\cup\{x|f(x)\not=g(x)\}$$

Now use the monotonicity of an outer measure along with the fact that the union of two null sets is a null set.

Comment: To appeal monotonicity of a measure, i think, firstly, it should be shown that $\{x|f(x)≠h(x)\}$ is measurable.

Comment: @Kaltus This is not necessary for an outer measure

Answer (score 0):

Concerning the measurability of $$ A = \{x| f(x) \neq h(x)\}$$

If $f$ and $g$ are measurable functions so is $$t(x)=f(x)-h(x)$$

Now note that  $$ A = t^{-1}(- \infty,0) \cup t^{-1}(0, +\infty)$$ which by definition is measurable.

On a final note, this works if the topological space you are mapping your functions into has the order topology, for example $f$ and $g$ map to $\mathbb{R}$ or the extended real line. If it is a general topological space think about what kind of set $A$ is. Is it open, closed? What happens when you take the preimage of it by a continuous function?